# Converting string to double keeps rounding to the whole number

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, double, rounding

I am trying to convert a `string` decimal number into a `double`, however when I use the `atof()` function, my number ends up rounding to the whole number.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string num = "135427.7000";
double r = atof(num.c_str());
cout << r << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
135428
```

I want:

```
135427.7
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cout` does that, not `atof()`.

More precisely, `operator<<`, which inserts the formated data into the [`std::ostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream).

You can use [`std::setprecision()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) from the [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) standard library to print the decimals:

```
cout << setprecision(7) << r << endl;
```

or

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << r << endl;
```

If you want to print the whole `135427.7000`:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << r << endl;
```